# "TextField " inside Row causes overflow flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a "TextField" inside a Row widget, my problem is that if I move it up using "padding" it gives me an overflow, probably because it is "Expanded" but if I remove "Expanded" the I won't see the "TextField", it disappears...Above the "TextField" there is an image.

And I would like to have only the borders of the TextField colorful, the rest must be transparent.

P.S. : Sometimes I don't see the "TextField", if I change color nothing seems change.

This is my code :

```
body: SafeArea(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: ()
       {
        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(new FocusNode());
        },
        child : SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Align(
                      alignment : Alignment.center,
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.99,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.49,
                        child : GestureDetector(
                          //onTap: getImage,
                          child : _image == null
                            ? CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/empty_profile.png'),
                            maxRadius: 80,
                            )
                            : CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: FileImage(_image),
                            maxRadius: 80),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
              ),
            Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.99,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.49,
                      child: TextField(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        obscureText: false,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.yellowAccent,
                              width: 3.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                          labelText: 'Descrizione:',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Edit : I'm using Align instead of Padding and is better but now my Circle Avatar of MaxRadius doesn't work...The size of the icon is doesn't change when I use a different "Minradius" or "MaxRadius", do you know why?

Comment: You want the text field to be right beside the image correct, instead of below it?

Comment: @Unbreachable it should be below, sorry for the late answer I was out.

Answer (score 0):

The *Row* widget does not impose any constraints on its children. You have the *Circle Avatatar* in a *Container*. Since you are giving the Container widget a specific width and height, it will take those measurements and apply them, but in doing so, it will ignore its children sizes(in this case the min and max radius).
You can read more about constraints here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

In order for the `disabledBorder` to function properly set `enabled: false` in the text field widget.

Comment: They don't have to be side by side, they should be above and below.

Comment: I don't understand, what is the first sized box for "sizedbox(width:20.0)"?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Unbreachable answer, you might consider wrapping your `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` if you want to use big sizes/paddings, otherwise, when typing and the keyboard is showing, your `TextField` will be probably gone, overflowed by the keyboard.